# Change text on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to change text in a div if the screen is less than..?

```
<a href="#">View full profile</a>
if(screen <= 768) {
   <a href="#">View</a>
}
```

Sorry I'm new to Javascript. I've seen similar questions around but any of them has a correct answer.

I know I could use css to achieve this but I don't want to repeat the html code just to hide/show elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Html:

```
<a id="viewLink" href="#">View full profile</a>
```

Javascript:

```
// Get the window width
if (window.innerWidth < 768) {

    // If less than 768
    document.getElementById('viewLink').innerText = 'View';
    // Change the link text to View.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Script

```
if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
document.getElementById('viewLink').innerText = 'View'; 
}
```

and HTML

```
<a id="viewLink" href="#">View full profile</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using media queries like here:

```
//css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .tablet {
        display: none; 
    } 
}
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
    .phone { 
        display: none;
    }
}

//html
<a href="#" class='tablet'>View full profile</a>
<a href="#" class='phone'>View</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method...

```js
if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
    $('#hide').hide();
}
```

```html
<a href="#">View <span id="hide">full profile</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <a id="viewText" href="#">View full profile</a>
    <script type=text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        if (screen.width < 768) {
            $("#viewText").show();
        }
        else {

            $("#viewText").hide();
        }

    });
    </script>
```